# How to convert a RDL to RDLC file with a different schema?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc, ssrs-2008, rdl

I'm using Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2008 to create RDL files, but also need to create a RDLC file. The problem is that SSRS 2008 uses a 2008 schema, while Visual Studio 2008 uses the 2005 schema.

***Is there a tool or work around for this solution?***

Note: I'm not using tablix, so that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any tool or work around for this problem and given the amount of similar or related questions elsewhere (e.g. [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/categories)) without any satisfactory answers I doubt something exist.

Of course you could always go ahead and write a XSL Transformation from the new [2008 schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/) to the old [2005 schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/), but given the amount of changes and especially extensions this would still be a tedious task with quite some possible loss of information, even while completely ignoring tablix.

Depending on your requirements you might be able to sit this out until Visual Studio 2010 is released, which is supposed to feature updated ReportViewer controls with on par support for the new 2008 schema. Unfortunately this release has yet see the light though, at least they haven't made it in time for beta 1, see ['Where’s the new Report Viewer?'](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2009/06/18/where-s-the-new-report-viewer.aspx).

Comment: I wish there was already some type of schema to schema conversion available for free that might have done this for me. Something similar that can be found in Biztalk mapping. I could always try to see if I could program something, but don't have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 includes an updated local mode report viewer that can consume 2008-style RDLC files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx

I have not tried it and I'd be curious to know if the control works with VS 2008.